# Allow short typo edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

I tried to fix a single-letter typo on this question:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/posts/705/edit

But it says: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Comment: TL;DR you're not the only user on that site. Drop in chat and tell others to edit a single typo if it bothers you so much, but since you need two reviewers to approve what you edited, *your* edits must be substantial.